# Force axios to interpret a "mathematic notation" as string

Tags: javascript, axios

I have an AJAX call which gets some string such as :

`9315554e54` but the fact is that they are interpreted as number `931555.4e+54` when they should be interpreted as pure string responses.

This is the code :

```js
return axios.post('getPath', {id_path: id_path}).then((r) => {
   console.log(r.data); // would give something like 931555.4e+54 when it should be 9315554e54
   // tried this which would not work since it will be incremented by 1 due to the mathematic notation : (9315554e55)
   console.log(r.data.replace(/(\+|\.)/g, '')) 
  }).catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error);
  });
```

Can I just get a string?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand--it sounds like you're saying it's coming back from the server as a number.

Comment: I don't think that this is coming back from the server as a number. The function I'm calling only deso this at the moment : `return "9315554e54"`. I think that the ajax query is interpreting the result before I get it

Comment: It sounds like you're not encoding the response as JSON on the server. So the returned string is being decoded as JSON even though it was never encoded in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `axios` library parses the response [using `JSON.parse` by default](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/5e0fb5fc998d7f9f5a897363977b42f4fa047238/lib/defaults.js#L57). This is part of the `transformResponse` parameter of the configuration.

If your response is a plain string, this function will try to interpret it as JSON.

```js
var parsed = JSON.parse('9315554e54');
window.document.write(parsed, ' ', typeof(parsed));
```

The solution is then to overwrite this default behavior:

```js
return axios.post('getPath', {id_path: id_path}, {
  transformResponse: (data) => data,
}).then((r) => {
  console.log(r.data);
}
```

or more succinctly,

```js
return axios.post('getPath', {id_path: id_path}, {
  transformResponse: null,
}).then((r) => {
  console.log(r.data);
}
```

Comment: Amazing, this is the answer I needed. Thanks you for the concrete explanation!